# Does indexes on dynamic nested keys works in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

Having the following query in PHP:

```
$where = array(
     "subs.{$pid}.opt"    => $subsType,
     "partner.{$pid}.lts" => array(
          '$exists' => true
     )
);
```

So, in my case a sub-key of "subs" & "partner" can be some symbols ($pid), different in different conditions!

I found, that query like that is slow because there is much data in my collection.

I tried to fix that by creating indexes:

1. compound index on "subs"+"partner"
2. compound index on "subs.$.opt"+"partner.$.lts"
3. also, tried creating a single index on that fields...

BUT, neither of these attempts were successful (I did "explain" on my query and saw that no indexes used in all cases).

So, my question: what I am doing wrong? Is there are possibility to create an index on dynamically-changed keys?
Or should I consider changing the way I keep data? (data structure)

Best wishes!

Comment: the only way to index something like this would be to change your schema somewhat (which may or may not be possible - it's hard to tell just based on the subset of information about full document given).  Keep in mind that you cannot have two separate arrays indexed in the same compound index - it's disallowed because of potential explosion of values to be indexed https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-826

Comment: Current data structure is like: {_id: ..., subs: {<someKey>: {opt: <someIntValue>}}, partner: {<someKey>: {lts: <someIntValue>}}}, where "someKey" depends on domain, language & other...

Comment: you won't be able to index that effectively. I would consider changing your schema - I would recommend considering all of your read and write requirements before deciding.

Comment: I think I should consider that advice: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/indexes/#how-can-i-effectively-use-indexes-strategy-for-attribute-lookups Changing schema to: {... subs: [ {pid: <someKey>, opt: <intVal>} ], ...} And after that putting index  on subs P.S: writes are rare & reads are 100x more often.

Answer (score 0):

In your original schema, each embedded object creates a unique field path in the document, so we can't effectively index those. A good illustration of these index limitations (and an example of refactoring one particular case) can be found in [this presentation](https://speakerdeck.com/jmikola/using-mongodb-responsibly?slide=35).

In your case, you might benefit from a taxonomy schema, akin to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17352074/162228), which I answered earlier today. [MongoDB Content Taxonomy Schema](http://hexane.org/blog/2011/05/16/mongodb-content-taxonomy-schema/) presents a good suggestion for a schema requiring arbitrary key/value pairs associated with a record. Additionally, it describes creating a compound, multi-key index (on two embedded fields within the same array) and using `$elemMatch` to query by a key/value pair. This example entails an array of objects, each of which has a key and value field.

An alternative schema could be an array of strings (e.g. `["key1=value1", "key2=value2"]`), which Derick Rethans uses in his blog article: [Importing OpenStreetMap data into MongoDB](http://derickrethans.nl/importing-osm-into-mongodb.html). If your keys and values are both strings, I would suggest this schema, but the aforementioned taxonomy schema may be better suited for non-string values.