# how to do taxonomy on metadata stored in mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, metadata, taxonomy

i have extracted metadata for some files(pdf,html,txt,doc) and stroed in mongodb in json format.
sample documents in my mongodb collection is as follows

```
{"Author: ":null,"Title: ":"java Syllabus","File name: ":"sample.htm"}
{"Author: ":null,"Title: ":"php Syllabus","File name: ":"sample1.htm"}
{"Author: ":null,"Title: ":null,"File name: ":"sample2.pdf"}
```

My requirement is to do taxonomy on above fields in documents.Is this possible?If its possible please suggest me .
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

By "taxonomy", are you hoping to store arbitrary key/value pairs for each document and later query by those values? You may find [MongoDB Content Taxonomy Schema](http://hexane.org/blog/2011/05/16/mongodb-content-taxonomy-schema/) a useful resource.

The gist is that top-level document will have a field containing an array of zero or more objects. Each of those objects will contain the key and value in their own fields. You can then create a [compound](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/#compound-indexes), [multi-key index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/#multikey-indexes) on the key/value fields within the array. Although compound, multi-key indexes cannot include multiple array fields (things could quickly get out of hand with indexing the [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of elements from each array), in this case we're indexing two fields within the same array.

To use your example data, you might have the following:

```
> db.foo.insert({
  filename: "sample.htm",
  taxonomy: [
    { k: "author", v: "Bob Smith" },
    { k: "title", v: "Java Syllabus" }
  ]
});
> db.foo.ensureIndex({ "taxonomy.k": 1, "taxonomy.v": 1 });
```

Per the examples in the linked blog post, you could query by key/value criteria, using [`$elemMatch`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/elemMatch/) to ensure the key/value are both contained in the same array element.